# jQuery mobile: How to create custom page transition

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am currently developing a mobile app using jQuery/CSS/HTML and I want to add my own page transition when I click the 'back' button. But I cant find any real good tutorials online on how to do this. I want to create a custom color 'transition' or something that is noticeable so that I know the transition is actually working and the default transition is not being called

This is what I have at the moment but it is not working and even if it was I dont think it would be noticeable enough:

.js

```
function myTransitionHandler( name, reverse, $to, $from ) {

var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
reverseClass = reverse ? " reverse" : "",
viewportClass = "ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning viewport-" + name,
doneFunc = function() {

    $to.add( $from ).removeClass( "out in reverse " + name );

    if ( $from && $from[ 0 ] !== $to[ 0 ] ) {
        $from.removeClass( $.mobile.activePageClass );
    }

    $to.parent().removeClass( viewportClass );

    deferred.resolve( name, reverse, $to, $from );
};

$to.animationComplete( doneFunc );

$to.parent().addClass( viewportClass );

if ( $from ) {
$from.addClass( name + " out" + reverseClass );
}
$to.addClass( $.mobile.activePageClass + " " + name + " in" + reverseClass );

return deferred.promise();
}

// Make our transition handler public.
$.mobile.transitionHandlers["myTransition"] = myTransitionHandler;
```

.html for back button

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="myTransition" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
```

Is there anything that i am missing and how would I make the transition stand out more?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this is a bit late, but I just figured this out, and thought I might post.

The problem is this:
The name of your transition, "myTransition", gets passed as the "name" argument to your myTransitionHandler function.

Since you have all the boilerplate stuff implemented in your myTransitionHandler (from the css transition handler), "myTransition" needs to exist in your css as .myTransition.in and .myTransition.out.

So, to fix this, you will need to either:

1. Add .myTransition.in and .myTransition.out rules in your css. or
2. Simply set "name" to something supported (like "fade") in the beginning of your myTransitionHandler function.

I think that's your problem, hope this helps...